# Splitting list into multiple lists - depending on elements index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with 4 Elements (The amount of elements is dynamic). Each element holds a string of 5 phrases/sentences in different language, split by ';' deliminator. The Languages are as Follows: ENG, FRE, GER, SPA, ITA. The phrases always appear in this order inside each element on the list. I am now trying to extract these Phrases from the whole list into by their own language List.

I've managed to split the list using the deliminator and 
I tried converting this list into a string and use string Slicing to get the result but I cannot figure out a way write it using code.

```py
list2 = combinedList .split(';')

hi = list2[0:2]
print(hi)
for element in range(0, len(list2)):
    print (list2[element])
```

Here is the original unchanged List:

```py
combinedList = [
'40% Football;40% Football;40% Fuball;40% Futbol;40% Calcio;',
'30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Basketball;30% Baloncesto;30% Pallacanestro;',
'20% Baseball;20% Base-Ball;20% Baseball;20% Béisbol;',
'10% Rugby;10% Le Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby;10% Rugby;'
']
```

I would like the result to be:

```py
ENG = ['40% Football, 30% Basketball, 20% Baseball, 10% Rugby']
FRE = ['40% Football, 30% Basketball, 20% Base-Ball, 10% Le Rugby']
GER = ['40% Fuball, 30% Basketball, 20% Baseball, 10% Rugby']
SPA = ['40% Futbol, 30% Baloncesto, 20% Baseball, 10% Rugby']
FRE = ['40% Calcio, 30% Pallacanestro, 20% Béisbol, 10% Rugby']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the strings in a list comprehension and use `zip`:

```
list(zip(*[i.split(';') for i in combinedList]))

[('40% Football', '30% Basketball', '20% Baseball', '10% Rugby'),
 ('40% Football', '30% Basketball', '20% Base-Ball', '10% Le Rugby'),
 ('40% Fuball', '30% Basketball', '20% Baseball', '10% Rugby'),
 ('40% Futbol', '30% Baloncesto', '20% Béisbol', '10% Rugby'),
 ('40% Calcio', '30% Pallacanestro', '', '10% Rugby')]
```